# Published output looking for wrong dependency

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-core, publish, visual-studio-2017

## Goal

I have two .NET Core console applications - `Application.dll` and `Updater.dll`. I want to publish `Updater.dll` (with all its dependencies) together with `Application.dll` to a folder using MSBuild publish.

## What I tried (Minimal Working Example)

I created a very small toy example which illustrates my problem (the solution can be downloaded [here](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/cMisY3cUEkzwXHr)).

The Updater source and project file look like this:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace Updater
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string SERVICE_NAME = "TestService";
            try
            {
                var serviceController = new ServiceController(SERVICE_NAME);
                Console.WriteLine($"Status of {SERVICE_NAME}: {serviceController.Status}");
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error getting {SERVICE_NAME}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The Application source and project file look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Application
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Updater\Updater.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- make sure the runtimeconfig of the referenced Updater is also included in the output -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\Updater\bin\$(Configuration)\netcoreapp1.1\Updater.runtimeconfig.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always"></Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Ant this is the publish configuration I use for Application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PublishDir>bin\Debug\PublishOutput</PublishDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I can successfully build and run these two programs in the debugger. I can also publish the Application project and the Updater and its dependencies are included:

```
PublishOutput\runtimes\unix\lib\netstandard1.5\System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.dll
PublishOutput\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard1.5\System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.dll
PublishOutput\Application.deps.json
PublishOutput\Application.dll
PublishOutput\Application.pdb
PublishOutput\Application.runtimeconfig.json
PublishOutput\Updater.dll
PublishOutput\Updater.pdb
PublishOutput\Updater.runtimeconfig.json
```

Also I can run the Application itself from the published output like this:

```
dotnet Application.dll
```

## Problem

I cannot run the Updater from the published output. When I try this:

```
dotnet Updater.dll
```

It crashes with the following exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>      at Updater.Program.Main(String[] args)

Interestingly it is looking for version 4.1.0.0 of `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController`. But as you can see in the project file, I'm actually referencing version 4.3.0

What am I doing wrong here? What do I need to change so that I can run the Updater from the published output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Updater.deps.json` was missing in the published output. The following change was needed in the project file of the Application.

Before:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="..\Updater\bin\$(Configuration)\netcoreapp1.1\Updater.runtimeconfig.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always"></Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

After:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="..\Updater\bin\$(Configuration)\netcoreapp1.1\Updater.runtimeconfig.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always"></Content>
  <Content Include="..\Updater\bin\$(Configuration)\netcoreapp1.1\Updater.deps.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always"></Content>
</ItemGroup>
```